# get checkboxes in drupal7

Tags: sql, jquery, drupal-7

I have a state dropdown (list in drupal 7) based on the selected item in that state table also i am having chekboxes. When i select any state from the dropdown, the cities under the selected state wants to be dislayed as checkboxes . My code is

```
function signup_form($form, &$form_state) {
 $form['rate_the_service']['state'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    //'#title' => 'State/Province',
    '#prefix'=>'<div id="dropdown-third-replace">',
    '#suffix'=>'</div>',
    '#options'=>$opt,
    '#attributes'=>array('selected'=>array('selected')),
 '#validated' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dcheck_state_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown-four-replace',
    ),
  );
   $form['rate_the_service']['city'] = array(
    '#prefix'=>'<div id="dropdown-four-replace">',
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => '',
    '#default_value' => isset($values['states']) ? $values['states'] : NULL,
    '#suffix'=>'</div></div>',

  );

}
```

Ajax call

```
function ajax_example_dependent_dcheck_state_callback($form, $form_state) {
   $state = $form_state['values']['state'];

       $state_query_result2 = db_query('SELECT cityname FROM cities WHERE varstatekey = :varstatekey', array(':varstatekey' => $state));

        $state_array = array();


       // $state_array[0] = '-- Select State --';
        foreach($state_query_result2 as $row2){
            $state_array[$row2->cityname] = $row2->cityname;
        }

        $options[$state] = $state_array;


    $form['rate_the_service']['city']['#options'] = $state_array;

    //print_r($form['rate_the_service']['city']['#options']);

    return $form['rate_the_service']['city'];


}
```

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Under your ajax function just return  `$form['rate_the_service']['city']`.
Then inside you form just after the state form element check for whether state form field is set or not. if it is set the do your sql query and collect city value in a array. after this you write you city form element  and in option assign the array which contains the city. Dont forget to use `isSet` function for the value of state otherwise at the time of form load the city array will be empty and give error.